# Missing ioctl-numbers.txt file in Documentation

Tags: drivers, kernel, documentation

I am not able to find `ioctl-numbers.txt` in the Documentation directory in kernel directory in `/usr/src`.

Where is it?

Comment: What makes you think you should find `ioctl-numbers.txt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The heavier parts of the documentation are shipped in a separate package, called [`linux-doc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/linux-doc). You can find the compressed file in `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc/ioctl/ioctl-number.txt.gz` after installing that package.

Comment: It was buried a bit deeper for me: `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc/html/_sources/userspace-api/ioctl/ioctl-number.rst.txt`